# How to make the other div box to follow the size dynamically using CSS?

Tags: css

Using CSS i use the following code. The problem is when one of the box have more words only the box expanded its size but the rest remain. How to make the rest of the box follow the size dynamically when one of them have more words. So that it will remain the same size for all

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #f69c55;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div"><span>IN THE MIDDLE OF NOWHERE</span></div>

<div id="div"><span>LIVING HELL OF CSS</span></div>

<div id="div"><span>LIVING HELL OF CSS no matter how many words inside the box itt will not dynamically expand but keep the size of the box at the same size as the rest so this is my stupid test to make sure every keeps within the boundary of the rectangle boxes all the time without exception. In any case it goes out of the box the word will be truncated for whatever stupid reason. Is this a possible scenario that the css can do or not?. So this is the longest words expansion for a test to prove the theory in the head. Or will the word start to squeeze in and fit within the box all the time or will it expand the box to become larger than it should whatever it is man man man. Oh yes now i can see the expansion of the box when the words exceed the length the box can keep within the rectangle size dimension</span></div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in CSS, then only the [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) supports it (*by using [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows)*).

(*See [css-grid support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)*)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid #f69c55;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div><span>IN THE MIDDLE OF NOWHERE</span></div>

  <div><span>LIVING HELL OF CSS</span></div>

  <div><span>LIVING HELL OF CSS no matter how many words inside the box itt will not dynamically expand but keep the size of the box at the same size as the rest so this is my stupid test to make sure every keeps within the boundary of the rectangle boxes all the time without exception. In any case it goes out of the box the word will be truncated for whatever stupid reason. Is this a possible scenario that the css can do or not?. So this is the longest words expansion for a test to prove the theory in the head. Or will the word start to squeeze in and fit within the box all the time or will it expand the box to become larger than it should whatever it is man man man. Oh yes now i can see the expansion of the box when the words exceed the length the box can keep within the rectangle size dimension</span></div>
</div>
```

---

updated css a bit to avoid a Firefox Bug (*now it uses [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for the [centering](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)*)

Comment: This is the best answer of all...but does it support older browsers and all browsers platform like safari, opera, Edge, IE older version, chrome, and older firefox?

Comment: @TheBANNED, my answer includes a link (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) that shows browser support for the CSS Grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for this ..and you are the best .

Answer (score 0):

fire this query as `$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element')` onChange event for this copyCss function you will need jquery.copyCss.js cdn